# Add a "sort" to a =QUERY statement in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I've setup a simple `=QUERY` statement that will pull targeted rows/columns out of a 'response' sheet and put them into a topic specific sheet.

```
=QUERY(responses!A1:K; "Select C, D, E where B contains '2nd Web Design' ")
```

What I looking for is a way to "automatically sort" the rows being pulled by two methods.

1. Alpha sort rows by one column
2. Date/time sort rows by one column

Any suggestions on how I can modify the above QUERY to automatically sort the rows?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use [`ORDER BY`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#order-by) clause to sort data rows by values in columns. Something like

```
=QUERY(responses!A1:K; "Select C, D, E where B contains '2nd Web Design' Order By C, D")
```

If you’d like to order by some columns descending, others ascending, you can add `desc`/`asc`, ie:

```
=QUERY(responses!A1:K; "Select C, D, E where B contains '2nd Web Design' Order By C desc, D")
```

Comment: can you please explain ORDER BY clause (ORDER BY C, D)? I assumed C and D were column headings, but it doesn't appear to be. Can you please expand?

Also, what if I want to sort by 'reverse' order? THANK YOU!

Comment: In my example, I have sorted on C and D column data. First the data would be sorted by C and then by D. You can use `DESC` to reverse the order in descending. By default its `ASC`, i.e. Ascending order.

Comment: This answer is to the point, but could be further improved by including how to choose ascending/descending, and if possible if these could be mixed. For instance, you’d might want to sort by gender ascending and birth date descending. Edit: I added this.

Comment: I was thinking there were no results in my query, it results that empty cells appear at beginning, so make sure you skip empty cells on your 'where' clause. i.e.
=QUERY(Vacaciones!A:D, "Select A, D Where A <> '' and D <> 'NO' Order By A asc", 1)

note the "a <> ''", and header = 1 (third param), so that title don't get included in sorted result

Answer (score -1):

Sorting by C and D needs to be put into number form for the corresponding column, ie 3 and 4, respectively.
Eg  Order By 2 asc")